# Opening 2 JSON files, comparing keys from specific values

Tags: python, json, compare

I'm trying to open 2 JSON files, and compare certain keys for specific values, this is what I currently have:

```
expected_file = open('expected_file_location', "r")
expected_data = json.load(expected_file)

compare_file = open('compare_file_location', "r")
compare_data = json.load(compare_file)


class CheckTests(object):

def value_Im_looking_for(self):
    for key in compare_data.keys():
        if expected_data["Value"] == compare_data["Value"]:
            print "The Values and Keys for JSON match!"
        else:
            print "The Values and Keys for JSON don't match"
```

Could someone explain why this isn't working, and potentially what I would need to do to get this to work properly. I'm new to python and especially with JSON, I've never tried using JSON values in a different python project.

Comment: Iteration variable `key` is set but never read

Comment: Try replacing `expected_data["Value"] == compare_data["Value"]` with `expected_data[key] == compare_data[key]`. You look up values in a dict via keys like this. You may also need to look at Python's dict `get()` method if a key from `expected_data` does not appear in `compare_data`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm